# Shell Script to Find ownerless Files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to figure out how to write a shell script for Solaris 10 that finds all of the ownerless files on the box using an if statement, prints the file names and locations and assigns them the root owner if they are ownerless.

Fairly new with unix in general and shell scripting.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
find / -nouser -exec echo chown root '{}' \;
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, remove the `echo` from the line above and re-run.

Dissecting the command above:

- `find` - The command you are executing
- `/` - Start looking for files at `/` (so look at all files)
- `-nouser` - Find only files whose numeric user ID doesn't have a corresponding entry in `/etc/passwd`
- `-exec` - Run the following command for all of the files that we found based on the previous conditions
- `echo chown root '{}' \;` - The command to run for each of the matched files.  `{}` is replaced with the full filename and the `;` is escaped so that `find` sees it rather than the shell seeing it as an end-of-command marker.

The `echo` is there so that you can validate that the appropriate commands will run before running potentially the `chown` command which might screw things up.

So you run the above once, make sure that the commands it prints out are good, and then you re-run the `find` command above but you remove the `echo` so that `chown` is actually executed instead of just bring printed out.

Comment: how would I make this into an if statement

Comment: Could you update your question with what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is still unclear... what is the point of the the "if" statement?

Comment: @SeanBright Well I'm wondering that the assigning of the file to the root won't work for all of the files unless its all in an array?

Comment: There is no reason for an array unless this is part of a larger script.  If it is part of a larger script, please include what else is in that script in the question.  Otherwise I have detailed what the command in my answer does.